# How I can seed products into database directly?

Tags: magento2.3, database

Sometimes I have magento installations where my coleagues do edit files in `./vendor` folder.  Therefore, using magento's seeder will require extra dependencies and may break the `./vendor` folder. As a result, I cannot use the existing seeder.

But instead I can make a seperate scrips that manipulates db directly. So what tables do I need in order to seed test products directly?

Answer (score 2):

Get all Simple products **(sku, qty, stock_status)** :

```
 select 
  catalog_product_entity.sku, 
  cataloginventory_stock_item.qty,
  cataloginventory_stock_status.stock_status 
from        
  catalog_product_entity join cataloginventory_stock_item on
       catalog_product_entity.entity_id=cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id 
join
 cataloginventory_stock_status on catalog_product_entity.entity_id =
             cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id
where type_id = "simple";
```

```
1. insert new product
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'simple', 'my-sku-test', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
[get entity id of new product]

2. Set status of new product using entity_id
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '97', '1', '17', '1');

3. Set visibility of product using entity_id
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '99', '0', '17', '4')

4. Set tax_class_id of product
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '134', '0', '17', '0')

5. Set filter_price_range of product
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '77', '0', '17', '100');

6. Set weight of product
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '82', '0', '17', '10')

7. Set quantity of product
INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`item_id`, `product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `min_qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`, `min_sale_qty`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `max_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `enable_qty_increments`, `is_decimal_divided`, `website_id`) VALUES (NULL, '17', '1', '1000', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1.0000', '1', '0.0000', '1', '0', NULL, NULL, '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '0');

8. Set name of product
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '73', '0', '17', 'my-sku-test');

9. Set url of product
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '121', '0', '17', 'my-sku-test');
```

Comment: Seeding would be to insert, not to query.

Comment: check my updated answer